# How to check that database is available and I can run queries after sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry)

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my code to initialize SessionFactory

```
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", pass);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", minConns);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", maxConns);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    configuration.addResource("TransactionBean.hbm.xml");
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I ran this code on the machine where no SQL database at all and all what i've got is:

```
16:27:24,719  WARN BasicResourcePool:1851 - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@62455eba 
-- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. 
While trying to acquire a needed new resource, 
we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of
allowed acquisition attempts (30). 
Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

That is only the warning message, there is no exception. 
I need to verify that the connection has been established successfully and I can proceed. Otherwise I need to change the parameters and try to connect to other database.

Comment: Which `Hibernate` version you are using?

Comment: <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>

Comment: It must be warn only , however you are getting exception as com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure and which is correct as you don't have database.

Comment: The exception is caught inside configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

Answer (score 0):

I think I should look here. 
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_connection_testing
I tried to implement it, but the validation is not working. It is another question.